# Top links added is showing twice?

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend, toplinks

I have added to links with following code in local.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink">
                <label>New Link</label>             
                <url>#</url>
                <title>New Link</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But "New Link" is showing twice in header links.Please suggest me a way.

Comment: I found whats wrong with this. Along with adding this code i have given layout updates to local.xml from my module's config.xml file. When i removed layout updates from config.xml its working correctly..